# Add CustomViews to a LayoutView dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a *LayoutView* in a *ScrollView* named *MyLayout* and I want to add a View composed by *LayoutView* with *TextView* and *EdiText* inside this *ScrollView* according a value,
for example with a method

```
addMyCustomViewToMyLayout(int x){
....
}
```

that adds the desired number of elements to the MyLayout in the ScrollView,

The CustomViews added to the ScrollView should be linked to the activity to get and set the value from-to the app.

Is possible?
How could I do?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing very special about ScrollViews.  You can think of them as a boundless View.  While normal Layouts like a LinearLayout are bound to an area, then ScrollView will allow its child to be whatever height it wants to be (or width in the case of a HorizontalScrollView).

ScrollViews contain one child.  The child size is bound by the width of the ScrollView, but it is not bound by the height.  Thus, the child will measure itself based on the idea that it has enough vertical space to show everything.

In this case, you create or inflate your MyLayout however you want. Then you add it to the ScrollView.  If you want to add other Views to it, you add it to your MyLayout layout view.  Just let the ScrollView do its thing.

Comment: I know what is the scrollview but I don't know how to add dinamically my custom layout as child of MyLayout and link this to Activity

Comment: You make the Activity implement the various event listener like `View#OnClickListener` and call `View#setOnClickListener` passing in the reference to your Activity.  You can also create your own custom Listener interface that works in the same fashion.  You set the listener when you create the object View.